# Como hacer varios select en oracle con c#

Tags: c#, oracle

Estoy ejecutando este select en oracle desde c#:

```
  select * from ( select  ROWNUM rn, a.* from ( select id,destinatario,titulo,prioridad,consulta,estado,fechaultima,compania,vista 
    from PAZKO.ALARMA_MOVIL where destinatario='xxxxx'  ORDER BY sysdate ) a where  ROWNUM <= 4  ) where rn>= 0;
```

Esto me funciona sin problemas. Sin embargo a la hora de agregarle uno o varios select más me da error. Este es el select que da error :

```
select * from ( select  ROWNUM rn, a.* from ( select id,destinatario,titulo,prioridad,consulta,estado,fechaultima,compania,vista 
from PAZKO.ALARMA_MOVIL where destinatario='xxxxx'  ORDER BY sysdate ) a where  ROWNUM <= 4  ) where rn>= 0;
select * from ( select  ROWNUM rn, a.* from ( select id,destinatario,titulo,prioridad,consulta,estado,fechaultima,compania,vista 
from NEWPAZKO.ALARMA_MOVIL where destinatario='xxxx'  ORDER BY sysdate ) a where  ROWNUM <= 4  ) where rn>= 0;
```

Como ven es el mismo select pero de diferente usuario. Si ejecuto esos 2 select juntos en sqldeveloper me funciona bien como se observa en la imagen de abajo :

[image: img]

Pero si lo ejecuto desde el código en la aplicación de c# da error :

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005):
> ORA-00911: invalid character    at
> OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32&
> cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType
> sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException&
> exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean
> bFirstIterationDone)    at
> OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String
> commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType
> commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl,
> OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64
> clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]
> scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection&
> bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64&
> internalInitialLOBFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML,
> OracleConnection connection, OracleLogicalTransaction&
> oracleLogicalTransaction, IEnumerable`1 adrianParsedStmt, Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF)    at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)    at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at
> ConexionesBD.oracle.Select.d__2.MoveNext()

El código es el siguiente:

```
 using (var comando = new OracleCommand(consulta, conexion))
                    {
                        var reader = await comando.ExecuteReaderAsync();


                        foreach (var item in reader.Cast<DbDataRecord>())
                        {
                           
                            //....
                        }

                    }
```

El paquete nuget que utilizo es el Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las consultas en secuencia funcionaran en un editor ya que permite realizar varias de ellas. Pero la conexion te permite ejecutar una consulta a la vez, ya que cada una por si sola genera un solo Dataset.

Segun entiendo, lo que intentas hacer es obtener los datos de ambos resultados y unirlos en uno solo. Para ello puedes usar una unica consulta usando UNION (ambos deben tener las mismas columnas de resultado)

```
select * from ( select  ROWNUM rn, a.* from ( select id,destinatario,titulo,prioridad,consulta,estado,fechaultima,compania,vista 
from PAZKO.ALARMA_MOVIL where destinatario='xxxxx'  ORDER BY sysdate ) a where  ROWNUM <= 4  ) where rn>= 0
UNION
select * from ( select  ROWNUM rn, a.* from ( select id,destinatario,titulo,prioridad,consulta,estado,fechaultima,compania,vista 
from NEWPAZKO.ALARMA_MOVIL where destinatario='xxxx'  ORDER BY sysdate ) a where  ROWNUM <= 4  ) where rn>= 0;
```

De otra manera, debes realizar cada consulta por separado en llamadas distintas.

Comment: Entiendo. Entonces en oracle no existe la opción de multiples result sets como en sql? En sql en la cadena de conexión se pone MultipleActiveResultSets=True y con eso se puede hacer tal cosa

Comment: Usar MARS (MultipleActiveResultSets) es posible pero la manera de utilizarlo es diferente. De todas maneras se hacen consultas separadas https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/manipulating-data#using-multiple-commands-with-mars